# How to separate components in Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have Laravel app, and create search box with [algolia](https://www.algolia.com) everything is good and the search is find but my question now for this code of Vue :

```html
<template>
  <ais-index app-id="myid" api-key="mykey" index-name="users">
    <ais-input class="search form-control shadow-sm rounded" placeholder="Search"></ais-input>

    <ais-results>
      <template slot-scope="{result}">
        <div>
          <h2>{{ result.name }}</h2>
          <h4>{{ result.email }}</h4>
        </div>
      </template>
    </ais-results>
  </ais-index>
</template>

<script>
  export default {};
</script>
```

I need spare the form ( ais-input ) in a place and put the result ( ais-results ) in another place of course same page

Something like that make two component one for input and second for result ( blew it will be in blade file ) :

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <search-box/> (<ais-input/>)
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <result-box/> (<ais-results/>)
</div>
```

Comment: yes, you can do it.

Comment: @FarshidRezaei pls, How?

Comment: you can create 2 components and place your sections in them. then  Put them wherever you want.

Comment: Yes, you can do it by creating a separate component and import it in your template. In your case you need to create `<search-box>` and import '<ais-input>` in your search box component and similarly the other components.

Comment: @FarshidRezaei yeah I know but what about the ( ais-index ) it contains the id and password of  algolia how can I control with it

Comment: guy's consider this part ( <div class="col-md-2"> ) in blade file not in component, so make my Vue code with two part of course the important thing is ( ais-index ) will be with which part ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering they seem to already be components, you can try to use them directly.
You can create two new Vue components, where you add the existing components:

```
<template>  
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <ais-input class="search form-control shadow-sm rounded" placeholder="Search"></ais-input>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the you can use them in your template as you wish.

Comment: but what about the first line (ais-index) it contains the id and password. + I don't want to put my code in components I need just the input and result in it other code be in blade. hope u got it

Comment: Consider the third section of my code which is ( col-md-2 ) in blade file